# Groupby columns and sort values descending by the count of rows for each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (df)  as follows:

```
 cluster    city    category    latitude    longitude   merchant
0   0   sanfran       10          39.072    -101.93253  merch2
1   0   sanfran       10          45.072    -110.93253  merch10
2   1   wichita       22          20.072    -100.93253  merch3
3   3   wichita        5          34.072    -99.93253   merch3
4   2   denver         1          40.072    -101.93253  merch1
5   1   longmont       4          30.072    -111.93253  merch2
6   1   longmont       4          30.072    -111.93253  merch2
7   3   topeka         5          20.072    -109.93253  merch1
```

And I want to get to this dataframe 'dfout'

```
  cluster   merchant    latitude    longitude   city    category
0   0        merch10    45.072  -110.93253      sanfran   10
1   0        merch2     39.072  -101.93253      sanfran   10
2   1        merch2     30.072  -111.93253      longmont    4
3   1        merch3     20.070  -100.93253       wichita    22
4   2        merch1     40.072  -101.93253       denver     1
5   3        merch1     20.072  -109.93253        topeka    5
6   3        merch3     34.072  -99.93253        wichita    5
```

Basically I want to group by the cluster and merchant within those clusters and count the number of rows each cluster-merchant combinations have and sort them by highest to lowest values i.e. the merchant who has highest number of rows in a specific cluster is on top and the rest of the merchants follows based on their row counts.

I can accomplish the following using the grouby statement, however thats where I get stuck.

```
df.groupby(['cluster','merchant']).count().sort_values(by='city',ascending=False)

                       city category    latitude    longitude
cluster merchant                
   1     merch2         2       2         2          2
   0    merch10         1       1         1          1
        merch2          1       1         1          1
   1    merch3          1       1         1          1
   2    merch1          1       1         1          1
   3    merch1          1       1        1           1
        merch3          1       1        1           1
```

Can somone shed some light on this issue please? how can I get from df to dfout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the desired output:

1. You need to use `.agg` with your `.groupby` and use the `first()` function for all columns except for one where you need to take the `count` (for sorting purposes later. I used the `cluster` column).
2. Since, I used the `cluster` column twice in the `.groupby`, I also had to rename it before `.reset_index()`, or an error would have been raised do to having two columns with the same name when resetting the index and bringing `cluster` into the columns of the dataframe.
3. Sort, by the criteria `cluster` and `cluster_count`, and pass `ascending=[True,False]`, so that you can sort ascending for the former and descending for the latter. Finally, dropt the `cluster_count` column.

---

```
df_out = df.copy()
df_out = (df_out.groupby(['cluster', 'merchant']).agg({'latitude' : 'first',
                                                  'longitude' : 'first',
                                                  'city' : 'first',
                                                  'category' : 'first',
                                                  'cluster' : 'count'})
          .rename({'cluster' : 'cluster_count'},axis=1).reset_index()
          .sort_values(['cluster', 'cluster_count'], ascending = [True, False])
          .drop('cluster_count', axis=1))
df_out
Out[1]: 
   cluster merchant  latitude  longitude      city  category
0        0  merch10    45.072 -110.93253   sanfran        10
1        0   merch2    39.072 -101.93253   sanfran        10
2        1   merch2    30.072 -111.93253  longmont         4
3        1   merch3    20.072 -100.93253   wichita        22
4        2   merch1    40.072 -101.93253    denver         1
5        3   merch1    20.072 -109.93253    topeka         5
```